# C++ while loop not terminating even after condition becomes false

Tags: c++, while-loop

I have written a heap building function that builds a max heap in an array. It starts from the last node and checks for each node moving up. It its on node 'a' currently, it checks for left and right children and if they exist and have value greater than 'a' then 'a' is swapped with largest of the immediate child nodes and this continues until the subtree is heapified. I have used a while loop for the trickle down part. It goes on until any of the children nodes have value greater than the current node, or at least it's supposed to. When I use a while loop with this condition, the loop never terminates. However, if I put a breaking if statement with the same condition within the while loop, it works. What's wrong?

```
void buildHeap(int arr[], int n)  { 
    int m= n;
    
    while(m){
        int i= m;
        int l= (2*i<=n)?arr[2*i-1]:INT_MIN;
        int r= (2*i+1<=n)?arr[2*i]:INT_MIN;
      
        cout<<l<<" "<<r<<endl;
        while(arr[i-1]<l || arr[i-1]<r){     //  <--- This doesn't work
            cout<<i<<endl;
            if(l>r){
                arr[2*i-1]= arr[i-1];
                arr[i-1]= l;
                i= 2*i;
            }
            else{
                arr[2*i]= arr[i-1];
                arr[i-1]= r;
                i= 2*i+1;
            }
            
            int l= (2*i<=n)?arr[2*i-1]:INT_MIN;
            int r= (2*i+1<=n)?arr[2*i]:INT_MIN;
            cout<<(arr[i-1]<l || arr[i-1]<r)<<endl;
            //if(!(arr[i-1]<l || arr[i-1]<r)) break;     <--- This works
        }
        
        m--;
    }
    
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
        cout<<arr[i]<<" ";
    cout<<endl;
    
    return;
}
```

I had used a simple example of array {1,2,3} with it. Following is the output.

```
-2147483648 -2147483648       <--- l and r for node 3
-2147483648 -2147483648       <--- l and r for node 2
2 3                           <--- l and r for node 1
1                             <--- while loop starts here, i= 1
0                             <--- The value of while loop condition is 0. Still it doesn't terminate.
3                             <--- i= 3
0                             <--- Loop condition still false.
7
0
15
0
31
0
63
0
127
0
255
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inside the loop, you have

```
int l= (2*i<=n)?arr[2*i-1]:INT_MIN;
int r= (2*i+1<=n)?arr[2*i]:INT_MIN;
```

This declares and initializes new variables `l` and `r`, local to the loop's body, and distinct from and unrelated to variables with the same name declared outside the loop. Those "outer" variables remain unchanged.

Your commented line with a `break` statement checks the "inner" variables, but the loop condition checks the "outer" ones.

Comment: Copy pasted it without thinking. I just discovered myself that after posting the question. Still, thank you!

Comment: @MuditSoni Don't use single letter variable names.  If you had used more descriptive names, issues such as name clashes like this are not as likely to occur.